# Highstock graphs with valid 0 values not generating a y-axis

Tags: javascript, highcharts, graphing

So when I have a chart that has nothing but 0 data (such as packet loss measurement) the Y axis isn't drawn unless you implicitly define a max and min value.

I have however a need for the graph to auto draw with 0 data without specifying a max as the max may not always be know (data throughput for example).

http://jsfiddle.net/fYkQy/2/ shows what I'm getting. see code attached

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    Highcharts.setOptions({
        global: {
            useUTC: false
        }
    });
    PacketLoss = new Highcharts.StockChart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            defaultSeriesType: 'line',
            spacingRight: 30,
            spacingBottom: 45,
            width: 600,
            height: 400
        },
        rangeSelector: {
            enabled: false
        },
        title: {
            text: 'PacketLoss'
        },
        scrollbar: {
            liveRedraw: true
        },
        navigator: {
            adaptToUpdatedData: true
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            tickPixelInterval: 80,
            maxZoom: 1440 * 1000
        },
        yAxis: {
            minPadding: 0.2,
            maxPadding: 0.2,
            min: 0,
            offset: 35,
            title: {
                text: 'PacketLoss (%)',
                margin: 12
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueDecimals: 2,
            valueSuffix: "%"
        },
        plotOptions: {
            line: {
                marker: {
                    enabled: false,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            enabled: true,
                            radius: 5
                        }
                    }
                },
                shadow: false
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: true,
            layout: 'horizontal',
            align: 'center',
            verticalAlign: 'bottom',
            x: 30,
            y: 35,
            floating: true,
            shadow: true
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'PacketLoss',
            color: '#660000',
            zIndex: 100,
            data: [[1373354992000,0],[1373361195000,0],[1373363923000,0],[1373380804000,0],[1373388550000,0],[1373392475000,0],[1373399655000,0],[1373409555000,0],[1373409858000,0],[1373410160000,0],[1373410765000,0],[1373411067000,0],[1373411369000,0],[1373411670000,0],[1373411971000,0],[1373412273000,0],[1373412574000,0],[1373412875000,0],[1373413177000,0],[1373413479000,0],[1373413780000,0],[1373414082000,0],[1373414384000,0],[1373414686000,0],[1373414988000,0],[1373415289000,0],[1373415591000,0],[1373415893000,0],[1373416196000,0],[1373416497000,0],[1373416799000,0],[1373417101000,0],[1373417402000,0],[1373417704000,0],[1373418006000,0],[1373418308000,0],[1373418610000,0],[1373418911000,0],[1373419212000,0],[1373419514000,0],[1373419819000,0],[1373420120000,0],[1373420421000,0],[1373420723000,0],[1373421025000,0],[1373421326000,0],[1373421628000,0],[1373421929000,0],[1373422231000,0],[1373422532000,0],[1373422834000,0],[1373423136000,0],[1373425197000,0],[1373432327000,0]]
        }]
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aBsqz/ shows how it looks with a set max and min (works with percentage values but not unknown values.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    Highcharts.setOptions({
        global: {
            useUTC: false
        }
    });
    PacketLoss = new Highcharts.StockChart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            defaultSeriesType: 'line',
            spacingRight: 30,
            spacingBottom: 45,
            width: 600,
            height: 400
        },
        rangeSelector: {
            enabled: false
        },
        title: {
            text: 'PacketLoss'
        },
        scrollbar: {
            liveRedraw: true
        },
        navigator: {
            adaptToUpdatedData: true
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            tickPixelInterval: 80,
            maxZoom: 1440 * 1000
        },
        yAxis: {
            minPadding: 0.2,
            maxPadding: 0.2,
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            offset: 35,
            title: {
                text: 'PacketLoss (%)',
                margin: 12
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueDecimals: 2,
            valueSuffix: "%"
        },
        plotOptions: {
            line: {
                marker: {
                    enabled: false,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            enabled: true,
                            radius: 5
                        }
                    }
                },
                shadow: false
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: true,
            layout: 'horizontal',
            align: 'center',
            verticalAlign: 'bottom',
            x: 30,
            y: 35,
            floating: true,
            shadow: true
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'PacketLoss',
            color: '#660000',
            zIndex: 100,
            data: [[1373354992000,0],[1373361195000,0],[1373363923000,0],[1373380804000,0],[1373388550000,0],[1373392475000,0],[1373399655000,0],[1373409555000,0],[1373409858000,0],[1373410160000,0],[1373410765000,0],[1373411067000,0],[1373411369000,0],[1373411670000,0],[1373411971000,0],[1373412273000,0],[1373412574000,0],[1373412875000,0],[1373413177000,0],[1373413479000,0],[1373413780000,0],[1373414082000,0],[1373414384000,0],[1373414686000,0],[1373414988000,0],[1373415289000,0],[1373415591000,0],[1373415893000,0],[1373416196000,0],[1373416497000,0],[1373416799000,0],[1373417101000,0],[1373417402000,0],[1373417704000,0],[1373418006000,0],[1373418308000,0],[1373418610000,0],[1373418911000,0],[1373419212000,0],[1373419514000,0],[1373419819000,0],[1373420120000,0],[1373420421000,0],[1373420723000,0],[1373421025000,0],[1373421326000,0],[1373421628000,0],[1373421929000,0],[1373422231000,0],[1373422532000,0],[1373422834000,0],[1373423136000,0],[1373425197000,0],[1373432327000,0]]
        }]
    });
});
```

Is this a bug? or am I initiating something incorrectly? Not sure whether this bug is only visible in the highstock fork.

Thanks

Comment: You can always set `minRange: 1` which will work better than setting min and max, see: http://jsfiddle.net/fYkQy/3/ Of course missing like is a bug (see answer by Sebastian).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a problem, reported to our developers [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2026)